# Dynamic where clause in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to load data based on Dynamic where condition.

```
string tempQry = string.Empty;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusid) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mktid))
    tempQry = "x=>x.MarketID==" + mktid + "&& x.MasterCustomerID==" + cusid;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusid)) 
    tempQry = "x=>x.MarketID==" + mktid;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mktid)) 
    tempQry = "x=>x.MasterCustomerID==" + cusid;

_lstOptInInterest = new LinkedList<OptInInterestArea>(
        (from a in _lstOptInInterest
         join b in _marketoEntities.CustCommPreferences.Where(tempQry)
         on new { CODE = a.Code, SUBCODE = a.SubCode } equals new { CODE = b.Option_Short_Name, SUBCODE = b.Option_Short_Subname }
         into leftGroup
         from b in leftGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select new OptInInterestArea()
         {
             Code = a.Code,
             SubCode = a.SubCode,
             SubCodeDescription = a.SubCodeDescription,
             CodeDescription = a.CodeDescription,
             PrevOptIn = b != null && b.OptedIn == true
         }).ToList());
```

It is giving compilation error `Where(tempQry)`.

`'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Market.Data.CustCommPreference>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments`

How to handle this?

Comment: Please format your code properly. It's hard to read right now.

Comment: See this blog for your answer http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: The error you are seeing appears to indicate that you are using EF not LINQ to SQL. Please correct your tags if that is the case. If you want to use strings, consider using [ObjectQuery's Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) method instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Where` awaits conditions in form of lambdas rather than strings, so you have to refactor your code a little bit (just an idea below):

```
IQueryable<CustCommPreference> query = _marketoEntities.CustCommPreferences.AsQueryable();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cusid)) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.MasterCustomerID == cusid);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mktid)) 
    query = query.Where(x => x.MarketID == mktid);
```

and later use it:

```
...
join b in query
...
```

Comment: @Anderi it says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<SPE.Marketo.Data.CustCommPreference>' to 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Market.Data.CustCommPreference>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @James123, try specifying type explicitly. See updated answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

see this blog by [Scott](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It should help you sort your issue

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing appears to indicate that you are using EF not LINQ to SQL. Please correct your tags if that is the case. If you want to use strings, consider using [ObjectQuery's Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338811.aspx) method instead of using DBSet. Alternatively, you could build the entire query using [EntitySQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx).