# Dynamic Where in linq with list parameters in action asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm working on a screen where I'm displaying the list of products but when the user clicks on different checkboxes, I got the value of checked checkboxes value in action parameter. Here is my screen.

[image: Product Screen]

Now what I want to request the query dynamically on different items selection.

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSpecificProducts
        (List<int> brands, List<int> categories, List<int> sugar)
    {
        var products = await _context.Products
            .Where(x => x.BrandId == ???)
            .Where(x => x.CategoryId == ???)
            .Where(x => x.Sugar == ???)
            .ToListAsync();
    }`
```

I've already take a look on some stackoverflow questions but I'm just getting results in case of single value like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17789612/9687763). How can I generate the dynamic linq on multiple where clauses.

Comment: use where(x => list.contains(x.someId))

Comment: One more thing please, sugar is my boolean property how can I deal with it, https://prntscr.com/jxxt0e

Comment: @UsamaShahid so why did you pass a `List<int> sugar` if `Sugar` is a boolean property? Instead of `List<int> sugar` it should be `bool sugar` in your parameters method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check that each collection is not empty before including it as a filter of your query like below:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSpecificProducts 
     (List<int> brands, List<int> categories, bool? sugar)
{
    IQueryable<Product> query = _context.Products;

    if(brands != null && brands.Any()) 
        query = query.Where(x => brands.Contains(x.BrandId));

    if(categories != null && categories.Any()) 
        query = query.Where(x => categories.Contains(x.CategoryId));

    if(sugar.HasValue) 
        query = query.Where(x => x.Sugar == sugar);

    var products = await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: One more thing please, sugar is my boolean property in the database. I'm setting the values against sugar and non sugar in this way, https://prnt.sc/jxxt0e. Would you please guide me what can I do it in this scenario.

Comment: @UsamaShahid  I edited my answer below. You should pass sugar as a `bool?` and set its value only when the user selected it.

Comment: @UsamaShahid and when the user selects Sugar and NonSugar you let the value  `null`

Comment: @UsamaShahid I haven't access to this page. It is blocked :) Can you add the error as a comment please.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type IQueryable<Product> to System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Product>

Comment: @UsamaShahid answer edited. Change `var  query` to  `IQueryable<Product> query`

Comment: @UsamaShahid Great it is working. Mark as accepted answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I would like to add one more thing, As we can see the method parameters are List<int> and in some cases they are null, so we on null value .Any() function throws an exception. So we need to add one more check here. `if (categories != null && categories.Any())` Similarly other checks as well.

Comment: 1 last thing is still remaining, our boolean Where statement is not proper working. `query.Where(x => x.Sugar == sugar)` here in this code `sugar` has true or false value. But it is returning all the items with true and false.

Comment: @UsamaShahid you should use it as follow: if user selects only Sugar then set true. If user selects only No Suger then set to false. If user selects both set null. If user select nothing set null :)

Comment: Friend, Yes I do like you guide me but in query I've only true in `sugar` but Where clause is not proper working with this check.

Comment: How do you pass the your value of `sugar` to your method? Consider adding another question for this specify issue please :)

Comment: Ooops! it was my mistake. I was missing to assign it again in query variable. `query = query.Where(x => x.Sugar == sugar)` Thank you so much @CodeNotFound

Answer (score 0):

when you want a list of `Product` where it's `brandId` is in the list of brands, `categoryId` is in list of categorise and `sugar` is in list of sugar, 
you can do it like.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSpecificProducts
    (List<int> brands, List<int> categories, List<int> sugar)
{
    var products = await _context.Products
        .Where(x => brands.Contains(x.BrandId) &&
                    categories.Contains(x.CategoryId) &&
                    sugar.Contains(x.Sugar))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

**----------Update----------**

as you have mentioned that sugar is bool property in your database, and as you are already suggested you can change your method's signature.

Also updating my code to check emptyness of lists, if lists are empty that means user has not selected any filter and thus we will ignore that criteria in filtering.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> GetSpecificProducts
    (List<int> brands, List<int> categories, bool? sugar)
{
    var products = await _context.Products
        .Where(x => (brands.Any() ? brands.Contains(x.BrandId) : true) &&
                    (categories.Any() ? categories.Contains(x.CategoryId) : true) &&
                    (sugar.HasValue ? sugar == x.Sugar : true))
        .ToListAsync();
}
```